# Error CS0021: Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type `UnityEngine.GameObject'

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to make a simple explosion using Unity Prefabs but it keeps saying

> error CS0021: Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type `UnityEngine.GameObject'

I checked the code and I can't find the problem. Here is what I tried:

```
public GameObject[] ParticlePrefab; 
public int amountOfPartcles = 3; 

// Use this for initialization  
void Start () 
{               
    for(int i = 0; i<amountOfPartcles; i++) 
    {
        GameObject ParticlePrefab = Instantiate(ParticlePrefab[Random.Range(0,amountOfPartcles)]);
        ParticlePrefab.transform.position = transform.position;
    }
}
```

Comment: The core issue is you have **two** things called `ParticlePrefab` - change the name of one of them.

Comment: Why would you be re declaring ParticlePrefab? you declared it at the top as an array now again as a local variable in Start.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you use the same name (`ParticlePrefab`) twice.

Also, are you sure that you want to the amount of particles variable to choose the particle. The way you do it, it could randomly crash if you have less different perfabs than the amount of particles needed.

Here is how you could do your start method:

```
void Start () 
{    
    const int numberOfPrefabs = ParticlePrefab.Length;           
    for(int i = 0; i<amountOfPartcles; i++) 
    {
        GameObject particle = Instantiate(ParticlePrefab[Random.Range(0,numberOfPrefabs)]);
        particle.transform.position = transform.position;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks it solved the index problem but now it says   Assets/Explosion.cs(12,46): error CS0133: The expression being assigned to `numberOfPrefabs' must be constant

Comment: Remove the const.